# javascript promises, the event loop, and the job queue

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
function foo() {
    console.log('foo');

    new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve('RESOLVING');
            }, 5000);
        }
    )
    .then(
        function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        }
    );
}
foo();
```

I am trying to understand what happens here correctly:

1. on executing `new Promise` the "executer function" is run directly and when `setTimeout` is called, an operation to add a new entry to the "event queue" is scheduled (for 5 seconds later)
2. because of the call to `then` an operation to add to a "job queue" a call to the passed function (which logs to the console) is organised to happen after the `Promise` is resolved
3. when the `setTimeout` callback is executed (on some tick of the event loop), the `Promise` is resolved and based on point 2, the function argument to the `then` call is added to a "job queue" and subsequently executed.

Notice I say [a "job queue"] because there is something I am not sure about; which "job queue is it?". The way I understand it, a "job queue" is linked to an entry on the "event queue". So would that be the `setTimeout` entry in above example? 
Assuming no other events are added to the "event queue" before (and after) `setTimeout`'s callback is added, wouldn't the entry for the main code (the call to foo) have been (usually) gone (run to completion) by that time and thus there would be no other entry than `setTimeout`'s for the `then`'s "job queue" entry to be linked to?

Comment: Are you asking about a particular implementation? Or for a language-lawyer definition from some standard?

Comment: @IvanRubinson A browser like Chrome

Comment: So [Googles V8 engine](https://github.com/v8/v8).

Comment: @IvanRubinson would there be that much difference in implementation between different browsers/engines? Is the behaviour not expected to be the same across the board for described scenario?

Comment: I dont think its necessary for the 2nd step to be added to the jobqueue the .then can just be added as a callback to the promise and synchronosly get executed after the promise finished (with no errors)

Comment: @jonathan no, promises always resolve asynchronously

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. on executing `new Promise` the "executer function" is run directly and when `setTimeout` is called, an operation to add a new entry to the "event queue" is scheduled (for 5 seconds later)

Yes. More specifically, calling `setTimeout` schedules a timer with the browser's timer mechanism; roughly five seconds later, the timer mechanism adds a job to the main job queue that will call your callback.

> 2. because of the call to `then` an operation to add to a "job queue" a call to the passed function (which logs to the console) is organised to happen after the `Promise` is resolved

Right. `then` (with a single argument) adds a fulfillment handler to the promise (and creates another promise that it returns). When the promise resolves, a job to call the handler is added to the job queue (but it's a different job queue).

> 3. when the `setTimeout` callback is executed (on some tick of the event loop), the `Promise` is resolved and based on point 2, the function argument to the `then` call is added to a "job queue" and subsequently executed.

Yes, but it's not the same job queue. :-)

The main job queue is where things like event handlers and timer callbacks and such go. The primary event loop picks up a job from the queue, runs it to completion, and then picks up the next job, etc., idling if there are no jobs to run.

Once a job has been run to completion, *another* loop gets run, which is responsible for running any pending promise jobs that were scheduled during that main job.

In the JavaScript spec, the main job queue is called ScriptJobs, and the promise callback job queue is PromiseJobs. At the end of a ScriptJob, all PromiseJobs that have been queued are executed, before the next ScriptJob. (In the HTML spec, their names are "task" [or "macrotask"] and "microtask".)

And yes, this does mean that if Job A and Job B are both queued, and then Job A gets picked up and schedules a promise callback, that promise callback is run *before* Job B is run, even though Job B was queued (in the main queue) first.

> Notice I say [a "job queue"] because there is something I am not sure about; which "job queue is it?"

Hopefully I covered that above. Basically:

- Initial script execution, event handlers, timers, and `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks are queued to the ScriptJobs queue (the main one); they're "macrotasks" (or simply "tasks").
- Promise callbacks are queued to the PromiseJobs queue, which is processed until empty at the end of a task. Thatis, promise callbacks are "microtasks."

> The way I understand it, a "job queue" is linked to an entry on the "event queue".

Those are just different names for the same thing. The JavaScript spec uses the terms "job" and "job queue." The HTML spec uses "tasks" and "task queue" and "event loop". The event loop is what picks up jobs from the ScriptJobs queue.

> So would that be the `setTimeout` entry in above example?

When the timer fires, the job is scheduled in the ScriptJobs queue.

> Assuming no other events are added to the "event queue" before (and after) `setTimeout`'s callback is added, wouldn't the entry for the main code (the call to foo) have been (usually) gone (run to completion) by that time and thus there would be no other entry than `setTimeout`'s for the `then`'s "job queue" entry to be linked to?

Basically yes. Let's run it down:

- The browser loads the script and adds a job to ScriptJobs to run the script's top-level code.
- The event loop picks up that job and runs it:

  - That code defines `foo` and calls it.
  - Within `foo`, you do the `console.log` and then create a promise.
  - The promise executor schedules a timer callback: that adds a timer to the browser's timer list. It doesn't queue a job yet.
  - `then` adds a fulfillment handler to the promise.
  - That job ends.
- Roughly five seconds later, the browser adds a job to ScriptJobs to call your timer callback.
- The event loop picks up that job and runs it:

  - The callback resolves the promise, which adds a promise fulfillment handler call to the PromiseJobs queue.
  - That job ends, but with entries in PromiseJobs, so the JavaScript engine loops through those in order:

    - It picks up the fulfillment handler callback job and runs it; that fulfillment handler does `console.log`
  - That job is completely done now.

---

More to explore:

- [Jobs and Job Queues in the JavaScript specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues)
- [Event Loops in the HTML5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#event-loops)

Comment: I had already distinguished between a "job queue" (PromiseJobs as per what you say) and an "event queue" (ScriptJob as per what you say). So when I say in point 2 [to a "job queue"] I mean the first not the second. Also, I did not say it would be added to the "job queue" right away, I said "organised to happen after the `Promise` is resolved".

Comment: @3m3sd1 - Sorry about that point 2 thing (fixed). Hopefully the answer did help address your questions, though? If not, what's still unclear?

Comment: @3m3sd1 - I missed some questions. I've expanded the answer to address them.

Comment: "*In the JavaScript spec, the main job queue is called ScriptJobs*" - I don't think there's anything in the spec about a main queue. Sure, in a browser implementation ScriptJobs go into the main task queue, but it's not necessarily so.

Comment: @Bergi - The initial execution of a script is done by adding it to ScriptJobs ([link](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runjobs)). To me, that makes it the "main" queue. :-)